# I want to change a order for reading array in python, do I have to use reshape?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I read a tif image(3D stack), and its original size is 100 X 120 X 150(example).

But, when I imported this, this size was 150 X 120 X 100.
I tried to reshape this by using matrix.reshape, but I figured out that if I used this reshape, its element order would be changed.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io

# read the image stack
fname = '100x120x150.tif'
data = io.imread(fname)
data.shape
```

What I want to do is changing a read order, while maintaining element order. So, after importing, I want to see data.shape will be 100X120X150 as original size order.

Comment: wait maybe its the right order cause the dimensions are 150( outer one, like samples) 120(outer image axis) x 100 (inner image axis)

Comment: Is `np.swapaxes()` what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Though `np.swapaxes` could be an solution to the answer, I would suggest writing a function that shows the orginal size information and keep the data not changed.

For example, from [SCIFIO](https://scif.io/images/) I pick up a tif file (focal1.tif in EmbryoCE.zip which size is 425 * 434 * 205) :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io

fname = 'focal1.tif'
data = io.imread(fname)

np.shape(data) #shows (205, 434, 425)
data[0] # The first layer in original Z direction

plt.imshow(data[0], cmap = "gray",  aspect = 'equal')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
print('Shape of matrix projection:',np.shape(data[0])) # shows (434, 425)
```

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmsXE.png)

You can easily plot a X-Y plane cross-section with using `data[number of slice]`.

---

And add a function that shows the original size info:

```
def pic_size(data_matrix):
    size = print('size of image: (',np.shape(data_matrix)[2],',',np.shape(data_matrix)[1],',',np.shape(data_matrix)[0],')')
    return size
pic_size(data) #shows size of image: ( 425 , 434 , 205 )
```

---

By the way, reshape is not a good idea, it gives out an image with dots that seems in periodical arrangement but no any useful information.

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSmMb.png)